# Is it possible to authenticate an AWS IAM user in a third party app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

In AWS, I can create a new IAM user, and choose a custom name and password.

Is it possible then to authenticate that IAM user in a third party app (in my case, a desktop app written in Java, for administration purposes), as I would do with Cognito in a mobile app, for example?

The purpose of it is to be able to have only one login and password to:

- access the AWS console with limited authorization
- call from that app APIs in API Gateway that are only available to administrators

Thanks for your help.

Comment: AFAIK, you can use other identity providers to authenticate in IAM (have a look at IAM federation), but you can't use IAM as the identity provider for another service (that's the job of Cognito as you said).

Comment: @eez0 That what I think too, but I wanted to be sure. Thanks.

Comment: You can try AWS SSO to manage identities. It supports SAML authentication, which can be used to log-in to 3rd party apps.